# jQuery Deferred resolve() don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

What i'm doing wrong?

```
function test() 
{
    var d = $.Deferred();
    var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
    if (name=="aa") 
        d.resolve(); 
    else
        setTimeout(test, 1000);

    return d.promise();
}
test().done(function() { alert("It's Ok!"); });
```

Comment: It does work just fine. http://www.jsfiddle.net/MQsbS/1/ make sure you are using jQuery 1.5.0 at least.

Comment: yes, it works only in case if "aa" is entered for the first time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work on the second name input is, you are calling a function `test()`, returning the [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) which then add's the ability to you original call to `test()` allow access to callback methods like `.then()`, `.fail()` and `.done()`.

However, if you do not get the input you wan't you are calling the function `test()` again, which creates a **NEW** [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Thus, the original call to `test()` which you have added the `done()` callback to will never receive the callback.

Change it to:

```
var d = $.Deferred();

function test() 
{
    var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
    if (name=="aa") 
        d.resolve();
    else
        setTimeout(test, 1000);
    return d.promise();
}

test().done(function() { alert("It's Ok!"); });
```

This was you are referencing the **SAME** [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and not creating a new one each time the function `test()` runs.

See it working **[here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/MQsbS/3/)**